# Add css class in DOM element of website

Tags: jquery

Is this possible to add a css class as hidden in dom element of website :

http://www.pricingindia.in/Search.aspx?q=mobiles+phones&cx=010882286766777081969%3Axkox132izzk&cof=FORID%3A9

You can see a  Here are ads coming from G. I want to hide those ads using jquery after loading.

```
<script>
       $(window).load(function () {
           $('#adBlock').addClass('hidden');
       });
   </script>
```

Jquery was not able to find this div tag, since it's in DOM not in source code.
FYI : It's experiment purpose only, i know it's not legal.
[image: See screenshot, if you are not able to find adBlock]

Comment: I don't think it will be legal to do that

Comment: there is no element with id `adBlock`

Comment: You can select any element on the page _including dynamically added elements_ with `$('#elementIdHere')` as long as you do that _after_ the element actually is added to the page.  Note though that it won't work on elements in other frames...

Comment: looks like the main problem is the element is created dynamically.. so when the script run in on load event it may not exists in the dom..

Comment: I ran the script after loading completed.

Comment: _"i know it's not legal"_ - In what sense is it not legal? Which law would it be breaking?

Comment: According to G. privacy. it's not legal

Answer (score 1):

Note that `#adBlock` is inside an iframe (with id `master-1`), which is inside another iframe (with name `googleSearchFrame`).

Then, you could

```
document
    .getElementsByName('googleSearchFrame')[0]
        .contentDocument
            .getElementById('master-1')
                .contentDocument
                    .getElementById('adBlock');
```

The problem is that the code above **won't work** because of cross-origin policy.

Image what could happen if you could modify iframes of other domains! The malicious site [bad.com](http://bad.com) could contain only an iframe of [bank.com](http://bank.com) (i.e. phishing). And it could add an event listener so that when someone enters his secret code, [bad.com](http://bad.com) knows it!

**Then, the answer is: YOU CAN'T** modify an iframe of another domain.

But you could always get rid of iframes: make you server connect to google (servers are not subject to cross-domain policies), get the HTML, and echo it as part of your page. Then, you will be able to style it like you want.

Or, you could always use an iframe with a search engine which allows you to hide ads. For example: [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/?k1=-1) with `?k1=-1` parameter.

Comment: So, Oriol what's the suggestion on this type of scenario? How can we get a particular tag?

Comment: @user1610100 You can't

Comment: @Oriol Ohhhh, the whole thing is in iframe. Heh.

Comment: @user1610100 You could also use [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/?k1=-1) instead of Google